# Crystal report data adjusting issue

Tags: crystal-reports

I am creating a crystal report which has a lot to show. I am struggling to pack information as close as possible at smallest size fonts using Arial. I have tried using several other fonts but no luck.

Comment: Please post an image of the report yoou have done.

Answer (score 0):

If using smaller text is not enough you can:

- set page orientation to `Landscape`
- reduce page margins
- change page size (you can use huuuuge page if you need),

(use **File\Page Setup**).

So more space will be available to fit your needs.

---

Anyway, you can use a multi-line detail like this:

Element **xyz**
   *First Name:* "abc" *Last name:* "cde" *Title:* "efg"
   *Address:*   "ghi" *Phone:* "jkl"     *Mobile:* "mno"
Element **zyx**
   *First Name:* "cba" *Last name:* "edc" *Title:* "gfe"
   *Address:*   "ig" *Phone:* "lkj"     *Mobile:* "onm"

and so on.

Comment: Already Done..! Thanks but Doing this also not solved my problem becuase i have around 50 feilds which needs to be accomodate in same page any other options pls. will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry,its not possible because the data in table format and it must be in a single row)

Comment: So: 1) you have 50 fields to display 2) must be in table format and single row. Just one solution: a page must be 1 meter large (2 cm per field). You can do this with Page Setup

Answer (score 0):

Go to page setuo and from there go to unit... there give maximum limit for horizontal component so that page display size increases and you can accomodate as many  fields as you wish with required font